# Show tags of currently popular (by views) posts

Tags: plugin-recommendation, tags, popular-posts

I'm after a sidebar widget that will show the tags of my site's currently (within the last day) most viewed posts, in order to achieve a rudimentary 'trending topics' widget.

Does this require a plugin (and if so which one), or can it be achieved with some nifty code?

Answer (score 1):

there is plenty of plugins in the wordpress directory. here is one
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/popular-widget/screenshots/